# How can we compile mulitple package specs in a bash script?

Tags: bash

The following is my code and I want to compile package spec(saved as .pks files) and if it contains any errors, script should through an error. However, this code is not working properly. How can I do this

```
spec=`ls *.pks -1|sed -e ''s/\.pks$//''`;
if [ ! -z "$spec" ] ; then
for i in $spec; do
compile_spec()
{
sqlplus -s @user << EOF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
SET LINES 255
SET PAGES 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TIMING OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET TERM ON
ALTER PACKAGE $i COMPILE PACKAGE;
EOF
}
done
PKS=`compile_spec`;
echo `$PKS`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "error"
  exit 1
fi
fi
```

Comment: Have a peek at the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), and also see about indenting your code so that it's more readable for anyone thinking to answer. Also, you say "this code is not working properly". How? What does it do then? Do you get some error message? Can you show a sample of a result you did expect?

Comment: Hello I want .pks files to be compiled and if any of the files contain errors it should show that the error is in particular file eg: echo "error" in $I. So my code here is not showing errors even if they contain. Actually what I think is when I run this code, the files are not being compiled.

Comment: Your `if [ $? -ne 0 ]` is using the return code of `echo`, the last command that was run, not `compile_spec`. Your `sed` command has useless quotes, but they won't be causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for i in *.pks;do
        i=${i%.pks}
        sqlplus -s @user << EOF
                WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
                SET LINES 255
                SET PAGES 0
                SET FEEDBACK OFF
                SET ECHO OFF
                SET PAGESIZE 0
                SET TIMING OFF
                SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
                SET TERM ON
                ALTER PACKAGE $i COMPILE PACKAGE;
        EOF
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "error"
                exit 1
        fi
done
```

I've just moved the `sqlplus` command out of the function, and put the `if [ $? -ne 0 ]` after it, so it should exit if `sqlplus` returns non zero. The script you posted had `if [ $? -ne 0 ]` after the `echo` command, which would return `0`.

I've also changed the `ls` command for a `find` command, as it's not normally a good idea to parse `ls`.

Edited as per ilkkachu's comment.

Comment: Using `find` instead of `ls` doesn't help much here, since e.g. whitespace in filenames will still cause issues with the `for i in $spec`. Just run `for i in *.pks; do i=${i%.pks}; ...; done;` to avoid the external program altogether.

Comment: Hello actually the code above is working fine but the problem is, it's showing file names prefixed with './' i.e., instead of pkg1 it is showing ./pkg1

Comment: Is the code working after ilkkachu's suggestion and my edit?